# \@dottedtocline{}{}{} indent argument doesn't work

Tags: table-of-contents

When using this command inside the class I'm working with (A thesis) the indentation argument isn't working. The weird thing is that the macro is capturing the first and third arguments which are the level and the num box width. I can't use the tocloft package because the class creates a conflict... So I hope you'll help me and thanks

```
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{5em}{3.2 em}}
```

```
% Definition of the table of contents command
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \chapter*{\contentsname \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \contentsname}}
        \begin{flushright}{\if@english Pag. \else P\'{a}g. \fi}\end{flushright}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
% Table of contents numbers and lines dimensions
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}


\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{0pt}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{0pt}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{0pt}{5em}}

% List of tables and list of figures
\newcommand\listoffigures{% 
    \chapter*{\listfigurename \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \listfigurename}}%
    \begin{flushright}{\if@english Pag. \else P\'{a}g. \fi}\end{flushright}
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \chapter*{\listtablename \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \listtablename}}%
    \begin{flushright}{\if@english Pag. \else P\'{a}g. \fi}\end{flushright}
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\let\l@table\l@figure % Command copy/paste
```

Comment: Did you enclose this in \makeatletter and \makeatother ? I think you have to if you're gonna use @ in redefinitions. Otherwise it causes problems.

Comment: If your class is conflicting with tocloft then it presumably has its own table of contents macros. Since you have given no information about them and no test document, it is not possible to say why those macros do not interact with `\dottedtocline` the way you want. Please edit your question to have an example that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll expand the issue with the parts relevant to the toc in the class.